# Facebook api stream table "Include recent activity stories" settings not visible

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-apps

Description field says

> Text of stories not intentionally generated by users, such as those generated when two users become friends. You must have the "Include recent activity stories" migration enabled in your app to retrieve this field

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

but when i go to application settings > advance "on migrates list".

i don't see option to enable recent activity stories. why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think this still holds true, but is just a remnant of an earlier version.

I am able to retrieve “X became friends with Y” descriptions without ever having set such a migration for any of my apps.